# Recording a Digital Piano

Tags: digital-piano, homerecording

I have a Roland Rp-102 which is an Upright Digital Piano. However, this piano doesn't have a recording functionality built in. So, I want to record my piano with the best quality possible ( Recording the actual sound not MIDI ).

So I bought a condenser Microphone ( Fifine ) and tried but when I set it up close to the piano , it collects some distortion of sound. as well if i put it away the sound becomes fair and unrealistic.

So can any one tell me a better way of recording a digital piano real sound without sound interface like zoom ? noting that my condenser mic is a usb cable as well that I want to record a descent realistic sound for a youtube video not an extremely professional recording for now.

As well note that the speakers of my piano are under the keyboard.

Comment: I fail to understand your reservation against the MIDI step. Converting a midi file using the sound font of your choice to a WAV-file beats all other solutions easily concerning achievable soound quality (since it requires no analog->digital conversion, where a condenser mic has its limitations.)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to record an instrument like this is by using the line-level outputs. Connect these to your computer via an audio interface (a 2-channel interface does not need to be expensive, you can get a basic one for less than $30).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, can you please recommend a suitable cheap brand you tried ? as  well I only have  Headphone jacks ... will that work with what you'r explaining ?

Comment: The outputs on the Roland can also be used as line outputs, according to the Roland website. I haven't bought any 2-channel interfaces recently, but any USB interface that allows you to adjust the gain of each channel will do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be trying the headphone out socket on the piano. Surely it has one? I've missed what you want to record it onto, though.